# Typechain and Batch Requests

Tags: web3js, typescript

I'm trying to send a batch request of transactions to my contract from web3. Using Typechain, my contract's methods are of type `NonPayableTransactionObject<void>`, which doesn't appear to support typing for that pesky `.request` method required of `batch.add()`. For example...

```
let batch = new web3.eth.BatchRequest();
for (let id of tokenIDs) {
    batch.add(myContract.methods.myMethod(id).send.request({ from: defaultAccount })   
}
batch.execute();
```

This produces `Property 'request' does not exist on type '(tx?: NonPayableTx | undefined) => PromiEvent<TransactionReceipt>'.ts(2339)`.

Is there another way of sending transactions to a contract via Batch Request using Typescript/Typechain?